# Drawing an 2d cone in android like a pie chart.

Tags: android

I am trying to draw a dynamic radar, but I can't get the cone shape to draw properly. I can get the two lines to work fine, but I can't get the shading between them to work.

My Goal:

[image]

What I am getting:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
RectF oval = new RectF(0,0,200,200);
canvas.drawArc(oval,(float)globalAzimuth+26, (float)globalAzimuth-26,false,paint);
```

globalAzimuth is the direction the phone is facing.  The radar spins as the phone does. The lines spin fine and synchorinized, but the arc just gets bigger and is obviously terribly off.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're treating the parameter `sweepAngle` as a *stop* angle. It should be the number of degrees to sweep, clockwise from `startAngle`.

[From the docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

> sweepAngle    : Sweep angle (in degrees) measured clockwise

Edit : It looks like you could use a constant `52` as the sweep angle, since you're just going 26 degrees in either direction from `globalAzimuth`(although your lines appear closer together than 52 degrees, so I'm not sure). If you do, you'll need to keep in mind that it goes clockwise, so your `startAngle` should be `globalAzimuth - 26`, rather than plus.

Comment: Thanks! This answered my question. Note: It is 52 degrees, but I manually drew the first pic so that probably isn't 52 degrees.

Comment: That makes sense. I was staring at it for a minute, wondering how you were possibly getting that with a 52 degree spread. Glad I could help.